# Suspicion that a term which has been claimed in be in use is actually invented - on topic?

Tags: support

I have stumbled over a certain word which claims to be the name of a refutation of an argument and it is also claimed that its origin is more than 30 years old. It is listed in Wikipedia.

The interesting part is now that *I am older and I never heard this word before in English literature*. This is easily explained as I am German, the trouble is that also Google Ngram *does not find the word in its corpus until the year 2008*. It finds "Deoxyribonucleic acid", "thermic lance" and nearly every technical obscure term I throw at it, but this specific word: zero.

Is it a valid question if I ask the community to check out if this word was actually used or known by own experience and find out in what **printed (!!)** dictionaries it occurs? References to internet resources are in this specific case not allowed at all.

Comment: That sounds like a question for [english.se]. Or a field specific site. Or you can raise your question on the Wikipedia article's talk page.

Comment: Yeah, come ask on EL&U. Now I’m quite curious.

Comment: @DanBron I would like to avoid EL&U because it personally feels like the worst place on Stackexchange. The people are extremely unfriendly and dismissive. EL&U was the very first place where I deleted my SE account voluntarily.

Comment: Still, I also am curious about what the word is.

Comment: @user6726 The word is ["Whataboutism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism). I am quite well-versed with names of arguments like *Tu quoque*, *Ignoratio elenchi*, *Poisoning the well* and some well-known killer arguments like *Godwin's law*, but this word comes out of the blue and I have never heard it before 2014.

Comment: If you go to Melbourne and read the newspaper "The Age" 17 June 1978 looking for an article by Michael Bernard, you might see a printed attestation. It will probably appear first in print in Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus, if/when a 5th edition comes out, since they have it in the online version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linguistics is the scientific study of language, as distinct from the hobby of collecting words or isolated facts ("the diminutive suffix in North Saami is -áč-"). The problem I see is that there isn't a linguistic question here. The question, as I understand it, is something like "Is the word 'superfalicragilistic' attested in [specified class of sources]?" – I don't know what constitutes a "printed" dictionary (is this about the medium, or about the publisher?). There is no scientific payoff behind that kind of question. We also don't have any truck with prescriptively-biased questions like "Is X a proper word of English". ELL might be better.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately ELL (as also remarked by other users) is not an option because I do not have the wish to participate in is-the-question-worthy-for-ELL, let-me-google-that-wrong-for-you, why-didnt-you-your-research-yourself-instead-bothering-us and why-dont-you-want-to-answer-our-completely-offtopic-snarky-comments.